# How to calculate Fama French & Momentum factor returns during Covid recession using their data website?

Tags: factor-models, fama-french, factor-investing, value-investing

We know that Covid Recession lasted during the months of `March & April 2020`. Using [Fama French data](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html), how do you calculate returns for factors such as `Value, Size, Profitability, Momentum, & LowVol`?

Solution 1: use `Fama/French 5 Factors (2x3)` for Value, Size, Profitability, and `Momentum Factor (Mom)` for Momentum. For LowVol, you can use Q1-Q5 on `Portfolios Formed on Variance` but is Value weighted the right option over Equal weighted?
The problem is Value for example is built different than when using 3 Fama/French factors.

Solution 2: use `Univariate sorts on Size, B/M, OP, and Inv` to capture factor returns by using Quintile5 - Q1 to capture factor returns. For Momentum one can use `10 Portfolios Formed on Momentum` but do we use Value weighted or Equal weighted? LowVol can use Solution1.

Just curious how other practitioners use it.